# How do i call the header files that are inside folders in my library folder if i added search path like this $(SRCROOT)/Library?

Tags: c, xcode, header

I have a hierarchy like this in my project

- Library

  - xfolder

    - x.h
    - x.c
  - yfolder

    - y.h
    - y.c
- sample
- sampleTests
- Frameworks
- Products

I added a $(SRCROOT)/Library in my Header search paths so i can call my headers inside the library folder. My question is do i still add a directory for it? like if x.c wants to include y.h do i place #include y.h or #include yfolder/y.h ?

I'd really appreciate answers, I'm still new to this and i want to add headers from ffmpeg source and it's really a lot of headers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of the following ways of `#include`ing `y.h` in `x.c`.

1. Use path relative to `$(SRCROOT)/Library`

   ```
   #include <yfolder/y.h>
   ```
2. Use path relative to `x.c`

   ```
   #include "../yfolder/y.h"
   ```

Comment: Thanks R Sahu. Just curious, if i also had an x.S and a y.S (in their respective folders) can i still do a #include <yfolder/y.S> in my x.S file? (considering i did option 1), my question now is regarding if the option1 still applies in different file types and not just .h or .c (or .mm) :D

Comment: @Miu, yes, you can. `.h` is only a naming convention. You can `#include` any file.

Answer (score 1):

You may use relative path as follows:
   #include "../yfolder/y.h"

Comment: Do i really have to add the ../ in all 1000+files? :( isn't there a way I can make #include start searching in my Library folder so I can just do a #include "yfolder/y.h" or maybe an <yfolder/y.h>? :) thanks for answering btw

Comment: I haven't tried it like that, but since f.e. <sys/types.h> does work like that, it might indeed work. But would't you have to make such change in all those files, just the same?